# Creating a button panel that continuously changes colors

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a button panel in Java that randomly changes its colors every second until a button is pressed. I've been trying to implement an actionListener and use javax.swing.timer, but it doesn't recognize timer.start() as a function of the timer class. Also, I keep getting an error that says my class ChangingButtons needs to either be declared as abstract or to implement an abstract method 'actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener. I'm also unsure how to make it stop changing colors after pressed.

```
public class ChangingButtons extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private static final int numButtons = 8; 
    private static JButton[] colorButtons;
    Timer timer;
    public ChangingButtons() { // creates the window
        newWindow(); //First creates grid
        setSize(400, 400);
        setVisible(true); // makes it appear
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    public void newWindow() {
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
        this.colorButtons= new JButton[numButtons];
        btnPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(numButtons / 2, 2)); // 8 buttons total; 4 rows
        Random rand = new Random(); //to randomize colors shown
        for (int jj = 0; jj< numButtons; jj++) { //creates the buttons and adds it
            this.colorButtons[jj] = new JButton();
            this.colorButtons[jj].setBackground(new Color(rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256)));
            this.colorButtons[jj].setOpaque(true); 
            this.colorButtons[jj].setBorderPainted(false);
            this.colorButtons[jj].addActionListener(this);
            btnPanel.add(this.colorButtons[jj]); 
        add(btnPanel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { //initializes btngrid
        ChangingButtons newWindow = new ChangingButtons();

        ActionListener action = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Random rand = new Random();
                for (JButton otherBtn : colorButtons) { //for(type item : item)

                    otherBtn.setBackground(new Color(rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256)));

                }
            };

            Timer timer = new Timer(1000, action);
        timer.start();
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `ChangingButtons` implement `ActionListener` when you don't use it as one?  You make a custom one in your main method instead

Comment: And which `Timer` are you importing?  `java.util.Timer`, `javax.management.timer.Timer`, or `javax.swing.Timer`?  You probably want to use the last one, but it sounds like you're using `java.util.Timer` _(the only one without `Timer.start()`)_